# Is there a way to reference a previous value in Pandas column without a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example if I wanted

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(5000)
df[‘A’]= 0
df[‘A’][0]= 1
for i in range(len(df):
    if i != 0: df['A'][i] = df['A'][i-1] * 3
```

Is there a way to do this without a loop?

Comment: `A` starts at 0. So no matter how many times you multiply you're still going to have 0. That aside, you're looking for [Series.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas-series-shift)

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to do? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your actual request (I doubt you want a dataframe full of zeros).

Comment: also FYI, assigning `''` (a `str`) to a column makes it of `dtype` `object`. Probably not intended, as you later assign numeric values to it (so through the loop the column is a mixed type value). You'd be better off assigning an initial value like `0`. Oh, and using Unicode single-quotes (`&lsquo;`, `&rsquo;` around `A`) is not valid.

Comment: I just updated it. I’m just trying to do that without using a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- your code sample has missing close brackets and quotes are not valid.  Fixed these
- if I understand what you are trying to achieve, multiply previous value by 3 where zeroth number is 1

  - initialize the series to 3, then set zeroth item to 1
  - then simple use of [cumprod](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumprod.html)
- shortened your series as this calculation will rapidly result in number overflow

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(20))
df["A"]= 3
df.loc[0,"A"] = 1
df["A"] = df["A"].cumprod()
```

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 9 |
| 3 | 27 |
| 4 | 81 |
| 5 | 243 |
| 6 | 729 |
| 7 | 2187 |
| 8 | 6561 |
| 9 | 19683 |
| 10 | 59049 |
| 11 | 177147 |
| 12 | 531441 |
| 13 | 1.59432e+06 |
| 14 | 4.78297e+06 |
| 15 | 1.43489e+07 |
| 16 | 4.30467e+07 |
| 17 | 1.2914e+08 |
| 18 | 3.8742e+08 |
| 19 | 1.16226e+09 |