# Is there a way to add a column to a list that does a datetime operation with another column's data, without using a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a time series using pyplot. I have a 2-D numpy array with the time data that looks like this (truncated array):

```
sndTemps_time = array([[ 0.      ,  0.      ],
           [ 0.041667,  1.      ],
           [ 0.083333,  2.      ],
           [ 0.125   ,  3.      ]]).
```

The first column represents the number of days since the simulation began and the 2nd column is the hour of the day.

The y-axis data is represented by the numpy array `avg_temps_in_z`.
Currently, I'm plotting (there's more code but here's the gist):

```
figure_handle,ax2 = plt.subplots()
ax2.plot(sndTemps_time[:,0],avg_temps_in_z)
```

to get a [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGOtj.png) with the x-axis labeled "Number of days since the simulation started" but I would actually like to generate a plot with the actual dates on the x-axis.

I have a variable `start_date`, which is in datetime format:

```
start_date = datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 24, 0, 0)
```

I know I could use a loop to get a list of datetimes, using:

```
#create an empty list for the dates
sndTemps_dates = [0]*sndTemps_time.shape[0]
#put start date in top row of list
sndTemps_dates[0] = start_date

for d in range(1,sndTemps_time.shape[0]):
    sndTemps_dates[d] = start_date + timedelta(days=sndTemps_time[d,0])
```

where `sndTemps_dates` is the new list, but is there a way to do this without a loop, using Pandas Dataframes or Numpy arrays?

This is different from [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67977760/is-there-a-way-to-reference-a-previous-value-in-pandas-column-without-a-loop)

Answer (score 0):

I simplify your problem:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([100, 200, 300, 400], columns = ['example'])
print('this is before adding a column')
print(a)
a['new_col'] = a['example'][0]
print('this is after adding a column')
print(a)
```

Output:

```
this is before adding a column
   example
0      100
1      200
2      300
3      400
this is after adding a column
   example  new_col
0      100      100
1      200      100
2      300      100
3      400      100
```

I think doing analog to this you will be able to solve your problem.

Comment: Using your example doesn't help me because I'm trying to insert a new column to the df with the first row value being a datetime, like "Dec 21", and then the subsequent rows being "Dec 21 + df.loc['rowindex','example']